# AttributeError: 'myNetwork' object has no attribute 'conv3', but the conv3 is right there

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm creating a simple tensorflow network like below:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, Dense, Flatten
class myNetwork(Model):
    def __int__(self, dim1: int, dim2, dim3):
        super(myNetwork, self).__int__()
        self.conv3 = Conv3D(filters=128, kernel_size=[dim3, 5, 5], strides=1, input_shape=dim2, padding='same')
        self.dense = Dense(dim1, activation="linear")
        self.flatten = Flatten()

    @tf.function
    def call(self, x):
        h1 = self.conv3(x)
        h2 = self.flatten(h1)
        out = self.dense(h2)
        return out
```

However, when running the code using:

```
out = self.PredNet(myInput)
```

where,

```
self.PredNet = myNetwork(dim1, dim2, dim3)
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'myNetwork' object has no attribute 'conv3'.

This is quite confusing, cause conv3 is right there!

Comment: You have a typo: it should be __init__ instead of __int__,
 
I think that's why conv3 is never set

Comment: OMG! That's it! Thanks a lot! How about you post it as an answer and I accept and close the question.

Comment: Questions caused by a typo should be deleted actually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor method always needs to be called `__init__`, not `__int__` or something else. In Python, the `__init__` method is a special method that is automatically called when you create an instance of a class. It is used to initialize the object's attributes and perform any necessary setup. If you name it something else, it will not be called when you create an instance of the `myNetwork` class. As a result, the attributes `self.conv3` and `self.dense` will not be initialized, so you'll get the "AttributeError" when you try to access them.